# Get one before the last created table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Found out this code to give me the lateset created table, but how can I get the one before it?

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'data'
ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Try using `LIMIT 1, 1;` it will return you the 2 record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of LIMIT 1, use LIMIT 1,1  this will give your second last created table