# Select one before the last record in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to access **one before** the last record in my table of database by using activerecord query in yii2.

For example like this:

```
$query = Product::find()
         ->where(['NOT IN', 'price_off', ''])
         ->orderBy('id DESC')
         ->limit('1,1') //But this limit not work correctlly
         ->one();
```

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968168/get-one-before-the-last-created-table-in-mysql) didn't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LIMIT` syntax for mysql is `LIMIT (offset, row_count)`. There is an `OFFSET` option which is not mysql specific. Yii's query builder has an [offset function](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#offset()-detail) that you should use instead:

```
$query = Product::find()
     ->where(['NOT IN', 'price_off', ''])
     ->orderBy('id DESC')
     ->limit(1)
     ->offset(1)
     ->one();
```